# Why does the binomial formula use multiplication?

Tags: probability

This is Problem 2.2 from Tsitsiklis, Bertsekas, Introduction to Probability, 2nd edition.

> You go to a party with 500 guests. What is the probability that
>   exactly one other guest has the same birthday as you? Calculate this
>   exactly and also approximately by using the Poisson PMF. For
>   simplicity, exclude birthdays on February 29.

To solve it, I used the equation $${499 \choose 1} \left({364 \over 365}\right)^{498} \left({1 \over 365}\right) = .348$$

I made a tree-and-leaf diagram where the root is your particular birthday and then there are 499 branches. Each corresponds to being matched with a particular person and each of those branches has two outcomes: the person has the same birthday or the person has a different birthday.

This seems like a total probability problem. But, the binomial formula suggests to multiply each of these possible outcomes together, instead of adding them.

Why isn't the binomial formula $$\sum_{i=1}^{n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

or, specific, to this case: $$P(B) = \sum_{i=1}^{n=499} (1/499 * 1/365)$$

The problem, as diagrammed in the tree-and-leaf visual, appears to be the same as a total probability theorem problem.

[solution from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNCrL.png)

Comment: Please, which is the question exactly, *why do we use multiplication* **where**?! What is that $\sum \frac 1{499}\cdot\frac 1{365}$ staying for, what are the terms?

Comment: The probability that *your* tree diagram solution answers is the probability that in a crowd of 500 people the person standing immediately to your right has the same birthday as you.  That is a different question than there being exactly one person in the entire crowd who has the same birthday as you.  The first level of branches being deciding who is standing next to you.  The second level of branches deciding whether said person has the same birthday.  In your proposed solution, you only bothered checking if the person standing next to you has the same birthday and didn't check anyone else.

Comment: @dan_fulea updated for formatting and clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, let $B$ be the event that exactly one other person has your birthday, and let $A_i$ be the event that the $i$-th person (besides you) has your birthday.  Then $P(A_i) = 1/365$, and $P(B | A_i)$ is the probability that no other person besides the $i$th has that birthday, which is $(364/365)^{498}$ by the multiplication rule, since the chance of any particular person not having your birthday is 364/365 and these events are independent.  If $B$ is true than the $A_i$ are mutually exclusive (since only one other person can have your birthday). 
 Thus

\begin{align*}
P(B) &= \sum_{i=1}^{499} P(B \cap A_i)\\
 &=  \sum_{i=1}^{499} P(A_i) P(B | A_i) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{499} \left(\frac{1}{365}\right)\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{498} \\&=  499\left(\frac{1}{365}\right)\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{498} \\
&= {499 \choose 1}\left(\frac{1}{365}\right)\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{498}.
\end{align*}

Comment: can you describe how you go from step three to four and why those produce the same result?

Comment: @Sebastian, we have the identity $\sum_{i=1}^n x = nx$, when $x$ does not depend on $i$, since we are adding up $n$ of the same thing.  e.g., $\sum_{i=1}^3 x = x + x + x = 3x$.